# goofys mount point on multiple linux systems

Tags: linux, mount, amazon-s3, fuse

I have a Minio bucket which is mounted on three different linux systems. the problem is when a file changes on one of mount points but file size doesn't changes that change doesn't get reflected on other mount points. Object on bucket changes but that change doesn't get reflected on other mount points.
I also checked timestamps on mount points and they were updated and same.
what is the problem?

mount command:

`goofys -o allow_other,nonempty --stat-cache-ttl 2s --type-cache-ttl 2s --endpoint [MinioEndpoint] --dir-mode 0755 --file-mode 0755 --uid [UID] --gid [GID]  [BucketName] [MountPath]`

goofys version:

`goofys version 0.19.0-943e017724ea820eb4185419ef3c41d6f921a324`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux - How to disable disk cache for a specific mount point?](https://superuser.com/questions/1389181/linux-how-to-disable-disk-cache-for-a-specific-mount-point)

Comment: Voted to close because asking the same question with different information provided in each part is frowned upon here.  You should merge both questions into 1 - https://superuser.com/questions/1389181/linux-how-to-disable-disk-cache-for-a-specific-mount-point/1389204#1389204