# Linux - How to disable disk cache for a specific mount point?

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, fuse

Is it possible to disable disk cache for a mount point on Linux system?
I have a s3fs mount on multiple systems and i need to disable disk cache for it. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

How are you mounting this?

I might try adding '-o stat_cache_expire=0,use_cache="",del_cache -o max_stat_cache_size=0 '

(Note that I have not tried this, I have compiled this by reading the man page and doing some googling)

Comment: I added `--stat-cache-ttl 0 --type-cache-ttl 0` but it doesn't worked, the funny part is that when the file size changes cache get cleared and fresh file is available on mount points but when the file size is the same as before nothing happens